Avoiding double redirects by .htaccess
By using the following .htaccess section I make sure that every URL is redirected to its https://www. version:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

Checking some redirect issues from Google Search Console with https://httpstatus.io/ I found out that all URLs like http://example.com result in two 301 redirects - 1st to the protected version and 2nd to the www version.
Is there any chance to always use just one single redirect?

If you are getting redirected from http://example.com to https://example.com first here, then that must have happened on another level already, before it gets to interpreting your .htaccess. Either your hoster does that automatically already via the server configuration, or perhaps you need to turn it off yourself in cpanel or some other UI.

Woah thank you so much! In fact disabling the "automatic HTTPS redirect" in the hoster's SSL certificate settings solved the issue. Really didn't think about this. Thanks!
